# How to make the shortcut « alt+tab » display over the opened windows?

Tags: 14.04, shortcut-keys

I use the latest stable version from Ubuntu.

When I use the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, it works (it still selects the differents applications opened, and switch between them), but when I have a window opened, it is displayed over the shortcut. It means that I can see the miniatures (from the shortcut) only on the desktop, without any opened window.

So my problem is that I can't see the miniatures anymore while selecting them when I have opened windows on my desktop.

Is it linked with the fact that, when I make a right clic on the side-bar (the menu-bar), the different actions appear under the windows too? (I can't read them neither.)

Do you have any idea how I can fix that please?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the output to `uname --kernel-release&&lsb_release --code --short` is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...